# Counting the number of words with restrictions on the consecutive repetitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

I have two similar problems which I'd like to post in the same thread because I don't want to take up too much valuable space.

> Let $w_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words from the set $\{A, B\}$ satisfying the condition of no two consecutive  $A$s, $a_n$ the number of words counted by $w_n$ that start with $A$ and $b_n$ the number of words counted by $w_n$ that start with $B$ so that $w_n = a_n + b_n.$
>
> What are $a_n, b_n$ and $w_n$, as terms in the Fibonacci sequence?

If a word starts with $A$, then the next letter must be $B.$ The number of all words that start with $B$ is $b_n.$ In this case we start counting from the second letter $B$ (subtract $1$ from the $n$ letters to account for the first letter $A$ which is not counted) so we have $a_n = b_{n - 1}$ for all $n \ge 2.$

If a word starts with $B$, then the next letter is either $A$ or $B.$ The number of all words that start with $A$ is $a_n.$ The number of all words that start with $B$ is $b_n.$ We know $w_n$ counts all words starting with $A$ or $B$. In this case we start counting from the second letter (subtract $1$ from the $n$ letters to account for the first letter $B$ which is not counted) so we have $b_n = w_{n - 1}$ for all $n \ge 2.$

Manually checking for $1 \le n \le 9$ we see that $a_n = F_n.$ [This should be proved more rigorously.I'll deal with it later, but for now it's enough that it's true. Is it true?] Since $a_n = b_{n - 1}$ we have that $b_n = a_{n + 1}$ and so $b_n = F_{n + 1}.$ Thus $w_n = a_n + b_n = F_n + F_{n + 1} = F_{n + 2}.$

> Keeping the limit of $1$ on consecutive $A$s and $2$ on consecutive $B$s, we include three more letters $C, D, E$ with no limits on consecutive occurrences. Using the notation $c_n, d_n, e_n$, notice that $c_n = d_n = e_n$ for all $n \ge 1$. Also, we introduce the notation $a'_n , b'_n$, etc., to represent the number of words of a given length that do not begin with a particular letter. For example, $a'_n = w_n - a_n$ and $a'_{n - 1} = w_{n - 1} + a_{n - 1}$. Show that
>
> $1. \ a_n = a'_{n - 1} \text{ for all  $n \ge 2$} \\ 2. \  b_n = b'_{n - 1} + b'_{n - 2} \text{ for all  $n \ge 3$} \\ 3. \ c_n = w_{n - 1} \text{ for all $n \ge 2$}.$

1. If a word doesn't start with $A$, then it starts with either of $B, C, D, E.$ By definition there are $a'_{n - 1}$ such words if we also account for the first letter $A$ that is not counted.
2. The words that start with $B$ either start with $B$ or $BB.$ In the first case there are by definition $b'_{n - 1}$ such words (also taking into account the first letter $B$ that's not counted). In the second case, again by definition (and taking into account the two letters $BB$ that are not counted), there are $b'_{n - 2}$ such words. Thus 2 holds.
3. There are no restrictions on words that start with $C$ and so if a word starts with $C$, then the first letter $C$ can be followed up by any letter. By definition there are $w_{n - 1}$ such words (we also keep in mind that the first letter $C$ is not counted).

Do my solutions make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first argument giving the Fibonacci numbers is perfectly sound.

It is easier to consider the final letter(s) of each word.

Let $a_n$ be the number of words (of length $n$) that end the letter $A$.

Let $b_n$ be the number of words (of length $n$) that end with a single $B$.

Let $bb_n$ be the number of words (of length $n$) that end the letters $BB$.

Let $c_n$ be the number of words (of length $n$) that end the letter $C$ or $D$ or $E$.

These satify the recurrence relations
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n&=&b_{n-1}+bb_{n-1}+c_{n-1} \\
b_n&=&a_{n-1}+c_{n-1} \\
bb_{n}&=&b_{n-1} \\
c_n&=&3(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+bb_{n-1}+c_{n-1}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
with the initial conditions $a_1=1, b_1=1, bb_1=0,c_1=3$.